# Join DB tables with hasMany association - store in array

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, join

In a cakePHP application I am building, a profile can have multiple locations; the tables are called "profiles" and "locations" and in the model classes I have defined a HasMany relationship. Now I want the user to be able to search profiles based on their locations. After reading some questions here and the CakePHP Cookbook, I have decided I need to use SQL joins (in reality more tables are involved, and the result of a search should be based on conditions concerning different tables).

I have written the following function inside my Profile model:

```
public function findProfiles($long, $lat){

$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'locations',
          'alias' => 'Location',
          'type' => 'Inner',
          'conditions' => array('Location.profile_id = Profile.id'))
    );


$options['order'] = array('Location.lng ASC'); //this is just as trial

return $this->find('all',$options);
}
```

The code works, but I get a copy of a profile for each location it possesses. That is, if a profile possesses 5 positions, I get five instances of that profile (each instance containing all five positions!)

How can I achieve this?

[edit]

eg. let's assume I only have one profile, with two positions. I get:

```
result[0][Profile]
         [Position][0]
                   [1]
      [1][Profile]
         [Position][0]
                   [1]
```

Where the data in result[0] and result[1] is identical.

Comment: could you post an example of what array you get and what you want? maybe it's because it's morning, but I don't quite get you...

Comment: Haha good question. Turns out that each instance I get actually does contain all the positions, in an array, just like I want. But if a profile has multiple positions, I get multiple copies of the profile, each copy containing all positions (ie. all copies are identical). Edited the question

Comment: and what is your `$recursive` value for the profiles and locations models? if it's not set to `-1` that's probably your problem

Comment: forget that, I get you now :) Uhm, it's your inner join. have you look at the resulting query, test it in your database, and get the result you expect? try changing you join to 'left' or do a `group by Profile.id` and see if that solves or changes your array to somewhat similar of what you want.

Comment: Ah awesome! the "group by" line did the trick. One question though, the Cookbook explicitly says "Remember that you need to set the recursion to -1 for this to work: $this->Channel->recursive = -1;" in the section on joined tables. But right now my application depends on recursive search. Is this risky?

Comment: Generally speaking is always better if you set recursion to -1 globally, and adjust your query (eg. when you need to retrieve 3 models, use Containable behavior (if you haven't checked it, *do it*)). When you hit a "Memory limit reached" php problem, you're going to remember this conversation and weep. *But*, if you still don't want to change it, you can just put `$this->Profile->recursive = -1` as the first line in the findProfiles function and you are set, it will just change inside that function.

Comment: Now, for this question, answer it yourself or delete it, or I'll answer it with a summary of all comments, but it needs to get "closure" by having an accepted answer or being deleted :)

Comment: I can't answer my own question for 8 hours because of lack of credits; so either you'll have to answer or I will do it tonight. Thanks a lot for your help! I will start implementing Containable behavior now.... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens because of the type of join used. With inner join you'll get this return with your query

```
profile_id      location_id
---------------------------
     1               2
     1               3
```

And cake understands that as two records of Profile, so you get repeated Profiles with the same info.

If this were all the extent of your problem, I'd say "go with Containable behaviour and forget joins", but since you said there are more tables involved, maybe the type of join can't be changed. So to get the unique Profile without repetitions, you'll have to GROUP BY the query to get

```
profile_id      location_id
---------------------------
     1               2 & 3
```

with a code similar to this

```
$options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'locations',
          'alias' => 'Location',
          'type' => 'Inner',
          'conditions' => array('Location.profile_id = Profile.id')),
          'group' => 'Profile.id'
    );
```

and you'll get rid of repetitions. For future problems like this, is best to first check the actual query that gets send to the DB, check yourself if the result that the DB gives you is what you want, and if not, see what you can do in cake to change it.